# Spring Boot - JpaRepository.findAll not returning data

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring Boot app.

Entity:

```
package com.example.demo;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FRUIT")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Fruit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String price;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + name + " : " + price + "}";
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FruitDao extends JpaRepository<Fruit, Long>{
    public List<Fruit> findAll();
}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/fruit")
public class FruitController {

    @Autowired
    private FruitDao fruitDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/all", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findAllFruits(Model model) {
        List<Fruit> fruits = fruitDao.findAll();
        System.out.println("Fruits = " + fruits);
        model.addAttribute("fruits", fruits);
        return "allFruits";
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8000


###
#   Database Settings
###
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

###
#   H2 Settings
###
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false

###
#   Hibernate Settings
###
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

When I go to http://localhost:8000/fruit/all, I see this in the console output:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        fruit0_.id as id1_0_,
        fruit0_.name as name2_0_,
        fruit0_.price as price3_0_ 
    from
        fruit fruit0_
Fruits = []
```

Basically, the query is correct but nothing is returned.
Going to the H2 database directly and running the same query, I do get a few records. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't write `findAll` in your `FruitsDao`, use the one provided by `JpaRepository`

Comment: Tried that. Got the same result.

Comment: Try to check correctness of path to this database.  Hibernate could not find this records, because  it connects to another database.

Comment: Do you have environment specific properties files? what is the value of your spring-profiles-active?

Answer (score 0):

maybe add `@column` on the top of private name, and private price, like that:

```
@Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
@Column(name = "price")
    private String price;
```